# How to join my object with its mirror modifier?

Tags: mirror

I have an object that I would like to have it joined with its mirror modifier (I've already selected clipping inside the mirror modifier's settings). How do I do this?
Here's an image of the half-cube separated from its mirror modifier:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select rim and move them to the center of mirror, until it stops by clipping plane:

[image]